Use typealias defined inside generic class in method signature
Given a generic class, one might have multiple methods which use a deduced type in their signature. To avoid repetition I would like to define a typealias. What is the best way to access it in a method signature?
class Y[X]:
    type Z = list[X]

    # this one works
    def works_with_pyright_but_ugly(self) -> "Y[X].Z":
        return []

    # these do not work
    def what_is_Y(self) -> Y[X].Z:
        return []

    def self_has_no_member_z(self) -> Self.Z:
        return []

    def what_is_z(self) -> Z:
        return []

    def listify(self, value: X) -> Z:
        """Just to show a slighlty more meaningful funciton"""
        return [value]

Is there a better way to reference Z in the method signatures?
In my view, what_is_z and listify do not work, because my editor does not list the value of the variable in the following example as list[int] as I would expect. Half the reason of type annotations for me is convenience in the editor (the other half being error checking).


Try add from __future__ import annotations at the top of the module

What do you mean when you say what_is_z and listify do not work? They follow the standard class-scoping rules in python. They seem to work fine for me in python 3.12.

@Dunes: I update the question with a picture at the bottom

You might need to update your IDE. Current versions of pyright show it correctly figuring out the type of Z. eg. https://pyright-play.net/?code=MYGwhgzhAEAaDaBNAugLgFDS9ALgTwAcBTaALWgF5oQBLCHJZTbZrAEyIDNoB9HmgHY0cfABQQiITgBpoANzAhU0RAEpoAWgB80AHIB7AUQzZT0CVIB0CkJXmL0raB24BbMAGsiPWvXGTOdW0yEzMsACciHABXcIFoeAtOa0UmdEi5IkUefGJRWFEARgAmAGZVS3cvHzocUVVVIA

@Dunes, I guess I will wait for the next pylance update, I updated my editor, and it went from Anylist[Any] to list[Any] which is half way there.The playground demo looks promising

Well, it's better than mypy. They just released their update for PEP 695 generics yesterday, and it throws an error on this code.

I just avoid using class-scoped types in method annotations.  If it's part of the class interface, I define it in the same scope as the class itself.

@Dunes assuming that the code snippet above is correct, did you create a mypy bug?

@ted Yes I did: https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/17956 It's where I got the suggestion for an intermediate alias.

A possible workaround that works for mypy, and hopefully the version of pyright your editor is using is to make your type alias generic over some parameter. When you use this alias, you parametrise it over the generic type introduced by your class. This allows the bulk of any complex type aliases to be specified in one place.
class Foo[T]:
    type Alias[S] = list[set[S]]

    def __init__(self, val: T) -> None:
        self.val = val

    def make_list(self) -> Alias[T]:
        return [{self.val}]

reveal_type(Foo(123).make_list())
# note: Revealed type is "builtins.list[builtins.set[builtins.int]]"

